# how to refresh TreeViewer and expand nodes as last time?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a puzzle. When I call the `refresh()` method to refresh the `TreeViewer` after saving the file each time,like this `treeViewer.refresh()` ， it always shows only the root element.

Before refresh

[image]

After refresh

[image]

I think it is necessary to write a method that refreshes and expends the node last time.like this 
[image]

The code I tried to implement this method is as follows:

```java
Object[] expanded = treeViewer.getExpandedElements();
treeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(false);
treeViewer.refresh();
treeViewer.setExpandedElements(expanded);
treeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(true);
```

But this method did not achieve the desired effect，And the content of the variable `expanded` gets correctly.I want to know if my method is correct? How should the correct method achieve this function? Or how to modify?

Comment: This should work provided you are not changing the objects that your content provider returns for the expanded elements.

Comment: As your tree look like mutli level deep tree. Check out https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=113675